# Strange behaviour with properties in Visual Studio 2015 Watch window

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, properties, watch

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private static Form1 form;
        private int count = 0;
        private List<string> list = new List<string>();

        public int Prop
        {
            get
            {
                Interlocked.Increment(ref count);
                list.Add("item");
                return count;
            }
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            form = this;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm running the following application in the Visual Studio Debugger, then pause it and add *Form1.form.Prop* as well as *Form1.form.count* to the Watch window.

I've expected that count is incremented every time I pause the application and view the Watch window. However, count remains 0 and and Prop is always 1. How and why does Visual Studio reset count after executing the Prop getter?

Comment: How do you test it? I can't reproduce it in VS2015. I have your code and paused the application. Then i'm executing following in the quick-watch-window: `((Form1)Application.OpenForms[0]).Prop`. The value always increases when i click at `Reevaluate`.

Comment: I've used the normal watch window. It seems that it does not re-evalate the expression when pausing the application a second time. I also see the value increasing if I delete the watch and re-enter it.

Comment: Ok, I've simplified the original code a bit too much. Now I've added a list. Although I can add Form1.form.Prop to the watch window and see its value is 1, the string list is still empty.

When I enter Form1.form.Prop in the quick watch window, I get the warning "This expression has side effects that cannot be saved to the process being debugged". What does that mean? Why can't the debugger simply run the getter so that the list contains an item afterwards?